# How to extract one field from wp_get_post_terms objects?

Tags: terms

I know I can get an array of term objects with this line:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytaxonomy', array('fields' => 'all'));
```

Or, I can get a simple array of term names with this:

```
$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytaxonomy', array('fields' => 'names'));
```

But I don't know how to extract just the names from the array of objects ($terms). This is so I don't have to call `wp_get_post_terms` several times.

Comment: You are correct about `names`. `$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'mytaxonomy', array('fields' => 'names'));` works and retrieve an array of term names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$terms` is an array of objects. You must select one of the array entries before you can reference its properties (fields).

This will print the 'name' of the first object (index zero):

```
if ($terms) {
   echo $terms[0]->name;
}
```

This will print all the 'name' fields:

```
if ($terms) {
   foreach( $terms as $term ) 
      echo $term->name;
}
```

Comment: That works. I can just make a loop to make a new array with just the names. I thought there might be a simpler way.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please accept it.